# Read anywhere from the memory by DelphiXE2 with Assembly x64

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-xe2, readprocessmemory

How can I access any memory address in `DelphiXE2` in `Windows7 64bit`?
I tried to use the `ReadProcessMemory` function, but it does not working.
However, I want to avoid to use the kernel driver to do this.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You just *have to* get the help of the OS if you want to read the memory of another process. Otherwise it is not visible to your program.

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory` **is** the right way to go. Please paste you code, maybe someone will spot the error.

Comment: Why two downvotes, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Why would you want to use ASM for that? ASM will NOT help you to cross OS boundaries

Answer (score 3):

`ReadProcessMemory` is a function that is known to work correctly. It allows one process to read memory from another process. But the addresses it uses are still virtual memory addresses. They are relative to the virtual address space of the target process.

I suspect that what you are actually trying to do is read physical memory. In which case there is no alternative to kernel mode. Only in kernel mode can physical memory be addressed.